# "model backing the context has changed since the database was created" error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Please help me how to resolved following error in MVC model.

```
The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).
```

Answer (score 0):

> This Error caused due to you have changed in Database and not into the ApplicationDbContext

To Solve this error:

Go to the Nuget Package manager Console and fire the **Update-Database** command.

After this Rebuild the project

hope this will work